# Why my entire edge selection suddenly stop?

Tags: mesh, edges, topology, selection-tools

When I select the entire edge suddenly the selection stop in that point as show in the picture.

Cant figure why!!! What I can do?

There's no ngon, no double faces, no double vertex......

Thanks for any help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: did u try fixing the normals?

Comment: Edge is selected if participates in a "4-way cross road". the selection continues by picking the edge with smallest edge angle to the previous one (like a car crossing straight ahead". In you case the edge comes to a 3-way cross-road and that is why the selections stops there (it could go equally in any direction, not just the one you think about). It always has to be a 4-way connection.

Comment: oh thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It meets a pole here, it doesn't know which edge it is supposed to select next:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!